How do PostgreSQL permissions work? Permissions needed to select from table
In order to SELECT from table I need:

CONNECT on the Database
USAGE on the Schema (Given implicitly to schema owner)
SELECT on the Table (Given implicitly to table owner)

Is this correct?

PostgreSQL has 3 layers of objects (Database, Schema, objects e.g. Tables) and also implicit grants given to DB object owners
That means we need

CONNECT on the Database
USAGE on the Schema (Given implicitly to schema owner)
SELECT on the Table (Given implicitly to table owner)

To see these privileges:

Use \l+ to see privileges of Database
Use \dn+ to see privileges of Schemas
Use \dp+ to see privileges of Tables

Privileges are seen here

We also need to understand acl entries of the following format:
grantee=privilege-abbreviation[*]/grantor

e.g. in the following \dp+ acl example user has been given all permissions by postgres role
user=arwdDxt/postgres

If the acl entry is empty, it means the object has default owner privileges (all privileges)
If the “grantee” column is empty for a given object, it means that privileges are given to PUBLIC role (every role that exists)
=UC/postgres

Also it's confusing when Public schema is used. You have CREATE permission on schema so when the tables are created with the same user you select data with and you have owner permissions out of the box.
Furthermore. Before you can do any of the above you must connect to the Cluster. This means connecting using a role with LOGIN permission using a valid password and SSL.

Note that the default permissions on schema public have changed in PostgreSQL v15.

That's correct and complete; the only exception is that there is no USAGE privilege on databases, so you don't need that.

I edited a bunch. I mainly created this question in order to hopefully help others due to roles confusion here. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=40186752

I think that your edit has confused the issue by adding a second question (how to interpret the ACLs). If you want to share knowledge, you should answer your own question.

Good point. Answered.
